# AR Vuforia move object by touch only in x z (Unity3D)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, touch, augmented-reality, vuforia

Im working on a augmented reality program and i need to move objects by touch in x and z coordinates. i have found a code in vuforia site to move objects. i tested this code but there are some problems, like object moving in Y so it goes to air !!!!! 
but i want to move my object only in x z (on ground scene)
i tried to change code to do myself but it hasn't any result.
please help me if you got it.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MyDragBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float maxPickingDistance = 2000;// increase if needed, depending on your scene size

    private Transform pickedObject = null;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
        {
            Debug.Log("Touching at: " + touch.position);

            //Gets the ray at position where the screen is touched
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                Debug.Log("Touch phase began at: " + touch.position);

                RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, maxPickingDistance))
                {
                    pickedObject = hit.transform;
                }
                else
                {
                    pickedObject = null;
                }
            }
            else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                Debug.Log("Touch phase Moved");

                if (pickedObject != null)
                {
                    Vector2 screenDelta = touch.deltaPosition;

                    float halfScreenWidth = 0.5f * Screen.width;
                    float halfScreenHeight = 0.5f * Screen.height;

                    float dx = screenDelta.x / halfScreenWidth;
                    float dy = screenDelta.y / halfScreenHeight;

                    Vector3 objectToCamera =
                        pickedObject.transform.position - Camera.main.transform.position;
                    float distance = objectToCamera.magnitude;

                    float fovRad = Camera.main.fieldOfView * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
                    float motionScale = distance * Mathf.Tan(fovRad / 2);

                    Vector3 translationInCameraRef =
                        new Vector3( motionScale * dy,0, motionScale * dx);

                    Vector3 translationInWorldRef =
                        Camera.main.transform.TransformDirection(translationInCameraRef);

                    pickedObject.position += translationInWorldRef;
                }
            }
            else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            {
                Debug.Log("Touch phase Ended");

                pickedObject = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested in manipulation for vuforia you can use [Lean Touch library](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/lean-touch-30111) for translations, rotation, scaling and much more (it will say that is deprecated, it works just as well).

Unfortunately Lean Touch does not have a script already made for  translation in zOx plane. For this I made this script based on [aldonaletto's answer](https://answers.unity.com/questions/550250/touch-screen-pos-to-world-pos.html). For multiple objects you can add some sort of selection pretty easily by using [Unity's Touch API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-phase.html)

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class MyDragBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
    {
        void Update()
        {
            if (Input.touchCount == 1 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                // create ray from the camera and passing through the touch position:
                Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
                // create a logical plane at this object's position
                // and perpendicular to world Y:
                Plane plane = new Plane(Vector3.up, transform.position);
                float distance = 0; // this will return the distance from the camera
                if (plane.Raycast(ray, out distance))
                { // if plane hit...
                    Vector3 pos = ray.GetPoint(distance); // get the point
                    transform.position = pos;                                      // pos has the position in the plane you've touched
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In my case I used these for ground plane detection but it will work just as well with target-based augmentation

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem yesterday. You need to chose World Center. Chose your ARCamera "World Center Mode" parameter from "FIRST_TARGET" to "SPECIFIC_TARGET" and chose your target, that is your Virtual World Center. Then try it in Play mode. Characters will move in your SPECIFIC_TARGET X & Z Axis.